# Send received data from ajax to another ajax as file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that returns a txt file and I'd like to post this received data to another form via AJAX

So the workflow is:
AJAX call --> success --> received a txt file --> send the returned data as file to another form via ajax

I tried with this code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "form1",
    method: 'POST',
    data: { field: field}
}).done(function(data) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "form2",
      method: "POST",
      data: { 
              file: data
      }
  });
});
```

The code sends the data but the form on "form2" does not receive a valid file object.

What can I do to convert the "data" recived into a valid file object?

Comment: Take a look into `FormData` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) and if you are sending a file and not just a long text string you should be using: `multipart/form-data` as the `contentType` (in combination with FormData)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, data is a reserved term,maybe use "response" instead

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lordvlad30 I used FormData() function to send the fields in the second form but adding these properties to the second ajax call:
dataType: 'json'
processData: false
contentType: false

And for the first call I must add 
xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob'
}

So the final example code is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "form1",
    method: 'POST',
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    data: { field: field}
    success: function(blob){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('textFile', blob, fileName + '.txt');
        $.ajax({
            url: form2,
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData
        });
    }
});
```